# Using max() on a function which gives a list returns 'int' not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I was solving a question to find the largest prime factor of a given number.
My solution:

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return factors
max(prime_factors(600851475143))
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-97fe3113b3b1> in <module>
     11         factors.append(n)
     12     return factors
---> 13 max(prime_factors(600851475143))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I can't understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You assigned an `int` value to the name `max` or `prime_factors` somewhere previously. (It's not clear which name is actually causing the problem.)

Comment: based on the code you have given this works. do you have a variable somewhere which is in int called prime_factors

Comment: @chepner nice spot, that will be the issue, see it all the time, people put an int into a variable called max then later try to call the max function not realising they overwrote what max now points to

Comment: I ran your code on my machine it works fine. May be the problem is what @chepner suggested.

Comment: I don't want to echo exactly what everyone else is saying, but pay active attention when you're writing code that the function that produces a value and the variable storing the value have different names. The situation will come up a lot, so it's a good habit to start paying attention to.

Comment: I haven't put max as a variable anywhere. Same goes for prime_factors

Comment: [check here](https://repl.it/repls/HelpfulMundaneAutosketch)

Comment: Hello, could you provide everything you're importing?

Comment: whats the output of `print("max:", max)` and `print("prime_factors:", prime_factors)`

Comment: @Ch3steR yeah its working but it isn't for some reason on my machine. I checked but I haven't made max or prime_factors as variable anywhere.

Comment: @Ch3steR prime_factors: <function prime_factors at 0x055DCE40>, but for some reason it gives max as 0 even though I checked it isn't a variable anywhere in my notebook.

Comment: @Kaneki ken ;) Type this in your notebook `del max` Should fix your error ;)

Comment: @Ch3steR Thanks that worked but I still don't understand how did that happen?

Comment: @Kaneki, you probably either declared max as a variable at some point or imported a library as max or a library's variable called max.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code above does not reproduce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the max function but the program thinks that max is an integer variable. My best guess is that you assigned an int to a variable named max somewhere earlier in the program.

To fix this issue run the code below before you call the max function:

```
del max
```

Then it should work because the code deletes the variable max.
Credits to Ch3steR for that one.